# Using a Comparison Operator on a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that I want to read in specific rows within certain ranges of numbers. If I use for example, `row['DISTANCE'] <= '300'`: the statement returns '300' but also any number greater than '300'. I want to write specific rows to a file in a certain range. Furthermore, it works if for example, the statement is if `row['SCHEDULED'] < row['PERFORMED']`. Any suggestions?

Here is a code snippet:

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as infile:

    reader = csv.DictReader(infile) 
    fieldnames = ['SCHEDULED','PERFORMED','AVAIL', 'DIST']

    outfile = open('ttest.csv','wb')    
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction = 'ignore')      
    csvwriter.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))

    for row in reader:
        if ['DISTANCE'] <= '300':
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

infile.close()                                                      
outfile.close()
```

This is a sample of what my outfile looks like:

```
SCHEDULED                        PERFORMED      AVAIL      DIST
142                                 139         19459      1061
22                                  20          0          278
21                                  19          0          278
21                                  20          0          278
22                                  21          0          1484
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare strings and not numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string comparisons don't follow the same rules as integer comparisons. What you want here is integer comparison, ie:

```
if int(row["DISTANCE"]) <= 300:
    proceed_with_row(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked the obvious.